# Oracle apex - Place field next to breadcrumb region

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I want to place an item\region next to breadcrumb region, but Apex doesn't seem to allow it, any ideas?
[image]

Comment: I believe the breadcrumb region spans the whole width. You could modify the page template to accommodate your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @KoenLostrie I checked the Page template and found the "Template Substitution" to which the breadcrumb belongs to. There, in the section "Display Points" need to check the "Grid Support" for this specific template Substitution.